# Loading svg files causes problems when using webstart

Tags: java, netbeans, jnlp, java-web-start

I have developed an application which I want to put online. When I generate a normal jar ( not intended for web start), the application runs just fine.

I generated a JNLP file to use for web deployment with Netbeans. When I try to run the application with web start, I get the following exception:

```
file:/C:/Users/Stefan/git/yt/WV/dist/Wetenschappelijke_Vorming.jar!/res/loading.svg does    
not exist or could not be read java.net.MalformedURLException
```

The piece of code which is causing the problem:

```
loading = this.loadShape(this.getClass().getResource("/res/loading.svg").getPath());
```

Webstart runs the application without a problem  when I comment out all the code relevant to the file I am trying to load.(I checked the jar and the file is located where it should e!)

Do I need to reference the images in the JNLP file? I'm a bit baffled and I've been searching for a solution, but cant to seem to find one.

this is the JNLP file which is generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="file:/C:/Users/Stefan/git/yt/WV/dist/" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Wetenschappelijke Vorming</title>
        <vendor>Stefan</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>Wetenschappelijke Vorming</description>
        <description kind="short">Wetenschappelijke Vorming</description>
    </information>
    <update check="always"/>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="Wetenschappelijke_Vorming.jar" main="true"/>
        <jar href="lib/controlP5.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/core.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/pdfbox-app-1.7.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/ESAPI-1.4.5a.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/lucene-analyzers-common-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/lucene-core-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/lucene-demo-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/lucene-queryparser-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/lucene-queries-4.2.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/gson-2.2.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/deploy.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/jsse.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/management-agent.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/plugin.jar"/>
        <jar href="lib/resources.jar"/>
        <extension href="jnlpcomponent1.jnlp"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="visualisation.Application">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of calling `getPath()` on the URL returned by `getResource()` is probably valid on your file system, but not elsewhere. Instead, use `getResourceAsStream()` to read the resource.